# Java regex not replacing my pattern

Tags: java, regex

Code:

```
record = record.replace("%icmp4-echo.*%","%\"icmp4-echo.*\"%");
```

record originally is:

```
%icmp4-echobalabalabalabala%
```

want to get replaced to:

```
%"icmp4-echobalabalabalabala"%
```

But my code does not work. Need some help or hint.
thanks!

Comment: @Pshemo From what I heard here on SO, `String#replace()` actually uses `replaceAll()` as part of its implementation.  But not in the case of the OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [String#replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
String input = "%icmp4-echobalabalabalabala%";
input = input.replaceAll("%(icmp4-echo.*?)%", "%\"$1\"%");
```

Here, we match the pattern `%(.*?)%` and then replace that with `%"$1"%`.  The quantity `$1` is a capture group, equal to whatever is inside the parenthesis.  As a side note, I made the capture group `(.*?)` non greedy, in case you want to replace multiple occurrences inside your string.